# Cannot use 'this' keyword in an object because it is inside another function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue.js in this case but I guess it would apply in plain JS too. The problem is that when I am in a function that is in another function I am having to call variables by their full path like - Object.variable instead of this.variable. Is there a way to use this.timer, this.pages instead of TVComponent.pages etc.

```
const TVComponent = new Vue ({
el: '.tvContent',

data:
{
    current_page: 0,
    timer: 0,
    pages: [
      { page: '/', interval: 10 },
      { page: 'tv/calls', interval: 10 },
      { page: 'tv/general', interval: 10 }
    ]
},

methods:
{
  tvTimer()
  {
     setInterval(function() {
        TVComponent.timer++;

        if (TVComponent.timer == TVComponent.pages[TVComponent.current_page].interval) {
           console.log('it is time!!');
        }

        console.log(TVComponent.pages[TVComponent.current_page].page);
     }, 1000);
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic problem of `this` being not what you expect in a function

A. bind it

```
methods:
{
  tvTimer()
  {
     setInterval(function() {
        // ...
     }.bind(this), 1000);
  },
})
```

B. use a closure

```
methods:
{
  tvTimer()
  const _this  = this
  {
     setInterval(function() {
        _this.timer ...
     }, 1000);
  },
})
```

C. use an arrow function

```
methods:
{
  tvTimer()
  {
     setInterval(() => {
        this.timer ...
     }, 1000);
  },
})
```

This is one of those things one has to *really* understand about JS in order to not fall for it over and over in different places. I suggest this ebook:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#this-identifier

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about binding and arrow functions. Will need to read up on it!

Answer (score 1):

The function you pass to `setInterval` receives its own context, however if you use an arrow function it will use the current context instead, and ignore the one given by `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(() => { ... }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `setInterval()` `this` object is not same as  vue.js `this`, since they have different scopes.

Try to assign `this` object to new variable before entering the problematic function's scope.

```
let self = this;
tvTimer()
  {
     setInterval(function() {
        self.timer++;

        if (self.timer == self.pages[self.current_page].interval) {
           console.log('it is time!!');
        }

        console.log(self.pages[self.current_page].page);
     }, 1000);
  },
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to bind it in this context. We do it this way in React classess.

Comment: how do you bind it?

Comment: You can use data.timer that is a better way